# How do you show a Dialog / Snackbar inside a useEffect on flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks

I'm trying to show a Snackbar inside useEffect hook, but it's show me an error. If i a understand well, i can't access the context from inside useEffect. So, how can i do?

This is the error: "Cannot listen to inherited widgets inside HookState.initState. Use HookState.build instead".

```
    useEffect(() {

      const snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text('Test'),
      );

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);

      return;
    }, []);
```

I'm trying show a dialog from inside useEffect.

Comment: when you are trying to show the snackbar?

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

`context` is the widget in the tree; it will only be mounted to the tree *after* inflation. Hence, delay things that need to look up stuff in the render tree starting at `context` to *after* the widget had been mounted to the tree; this is the case after the first render frame:

```
useEffect(() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    showDialog(
      context: context, 
      ...
    );
  });
}, []);
```

## Not too long, I want to understand and read it

Understanding the fundamentals of the render process of a widget will shed light on the darkness.

### Why can't I show a dialog in `useEffect`/`initState`?

First of all, note that this is not a hooks-related topic, but in more general, the error would also show up, if you try to call `showDialog` (or similiar) in the `initState` method of a stateful widget. Here is why:

`context` refers to the location of the widget in the tree. Before flutter can put the widget in the tree it needs to inflate the widget. This inflation is the first render frame of the widget and during this inflation process flutter will call `initState` to set up all parameters of the widget in order to then call `build(context)` to render the widget and then flutter would mount the context (i.e. the widget) to the tree. The hooks lib analog is `useEffect((){}, [])` which also runs during this inflation process.

When calling `showDialog(context: context, ...)` flutter needs to lookup the next `Overlay` widget in the render tree and it will walk up the render tree starting from the given `context`, but during inflation **the context (i.e. the widget) is not yet mounted to the tree**. Hence, you see this error.

### But how can I show a dialog (or similar) on the first render?

Well, you cannot do it *during* the first render, but you can do it *after* the inflation process is completed and the widget is mounted to the tree. There are several ways of doing it.

- use `addPostFrameCallback` to delay execution of the callback to after the rendering of the current frame:

  ```
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      showDialog(
        context: context, 
        ...
      );
    });
  }
  ```
- use a lib like https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout . It is a mixin for stateful widgets that provides a method:

  ```
  @override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(context: context, ...);
  }
  ```

### How can I do it during `useEffect`?

Again, you cannot look up things in the render tree starting from `context` when `context` is not mounted to the tree. This means, you cannot do it *during* the effect, but must delay execution to *after* the widget has been mounted to the tree:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  useEffect(() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      showDialog(
        context: context, 
        ...
      );
    });
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: The addPostFrameCallback indeed works, thanks! Used for showing SnackBar.